# iterating with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to find a way to access previous values from a Linq method in the same line.

I want to be able to use this general form in Linq:

```
var values = Enumerable.Range( 1, 100 ).Select( i => i + [last result] );
```

But I can't find a way to do something like this without multi-line lambda's and storing the results somewhere else.

So the best fibonacci sum I've been able to do in Linq is:

```
List<int> calculated = new List<int>( new int[] { 1, 2 });
var fibonacci = Enumerable.Range(2, 10).Select(i =>
    {
        int result = calculated[i - 2] + calculated[i - 1];
        calculated.Add(result);
        return result; // and how could I just put the result in fibonacci?
    }
);
```

Which seems ugly. I could do this in less code with a regular for loop.

```
for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
{
    calculated.Add(calculated[i - 2] + calculated[i - 1]);
}
```

It seems like if I could find a way to do this, I could use Linq to do a lot of Linear programming and sum a lot of iterative formulas.

Comment: LINQ, as the last letter of the acronym suggests, is for Querying. Not for calculations... Don't shoehorn it into something it isn't.

Comment: @Oded: that is probably "the answer". I am still trying to learn Linq's boundaries. I can think of 2 job interviews where I coulda/shoulda said what you did (although a bit more gently). Could you submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to create a Fibonacci sequence generator, you would be better off writing your own generator function instead of using Linq extension methods.  Something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Fibonacci()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 0;
    int last;

    for (;;) {
        yield return a;

        last = a;
        a += b;
        b = last;
    }
}
```

Then you can apply Linq methods to this enumerable to achieve the result you want (try iterating over `Fibonacci().Take(20)` for example).

Linq extension methods are not the solution for every programming problem, and I can only imagine how horrid a pure LINQ Fibonacci sequence generator would look.

Comment: I don't think that using the generator pattern to generate an infinite sequence is putting a square peg in a round hole.  In fact, it can be rather useful.

Comment: Howie - My comment was about that very last sentence, in particular "Linq extension methods are not the solution for every programming problem.". I was agreeing.

Comment: Now if only we could write these generators with a bit less syntax.

Comment: I would move the last sentence to its own paragraph. It kind of jumps out at you.

Answer (score 1):

Closest you can come to something like that with LINQ is the [IEnumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) method (a.k.a. fold from functional programming). You can use it to, for example, sum up the squares of a collection, like:

```
int sumSquares = list.Aggregate(0, (sum, item) => sum + item * item);
```

Since in LINQ the values are retrieved from a collection using an enumerator, i.e. they are taken one by one, by definition, there is no concept of "previous item". The items could even be generated and discarded on the fly, using some `yield return` magic. That said, you could always use some hack like:

```
long a= 1;
long b= 1;
var fibonacci = Enumerable.Range(1,20).Select(i => {
  long last= a + b;
  b = a;
  a = last;
  return last;
});
```

but the moment you have to use and modify an outside variable to make the lambdas work, you are in code-smell territory.

Comment: I don't like that they chose the name aggregate for some reason. Somehow it makes the resulting expression less elegant to me.